# http_basic_authenticate_with not working. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just started learning ruby-on-rails by using this stuff:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

And I'm stopped on this step:

**10 Security**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  http_basic_authenticate_with :name => "dhh", :password => "secret", :except => [:index, :show]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
    respond_to do |format|

    [...]


class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  http_basic_authenticate_with :name => "dhh", :password => "secret", :only => :destroy

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])

    [...]
```

And it didn't work. I mean, there is no prompt for a password and login, and there is no error. I just did that and nothing changed.

Can someone help me with that or at least point me in the right direction to solve the problem?

Comment: What actions are you calling where there is no authentication request? In your first example `index` and `show` will not ask for a password, in your second example only `destroy` will be password protected.

Comment: I understand that. But I can destroy, create and do every possible thing without authorization request. That where is the problem. Code just didnt work and Im interested why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the version of Rails you have. If it's 3.2 it should work properly, as you can see at the top of the page it says:

**This Guide is based on Rails 3.2. Some of the code shown here will not work in earlier versions of Rails.**

So you might wanna check that first, then if your version is an earlier one then try this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
USER, PASSWORD = 'dhh', 'secret'

before_filter :authentication_check, :except => :index

#Any other method

 private
  def authentication_check
   authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |user, password|
    user == USER && password == PASSWORD
   end
  end
end
```

It should work properly. Then, last option, you might have given the proper credentials once and now the app remembers that it's you and allows you to do everything, so (just to be sure) try to change the user name in anything else. You wanna edit the line to make it look like this:

```
http_basic_authenticate_with :name => "anotherName", :password => "secret", :except => [:index, :show]
```

Obviously this line of code (as stated begore) will work only on Rails 3.2 (I actually think it should work on the 3.1 too) or more.

Comment: Its not working with Rails-4.2.* version as giving the error "undefined method `http_basic_authenticate_with' for"